# Coding genotypes from nucleotides to 0/1/2 in R (or Python)

Tags: python, r, bioinformatics

I have a data table with dbSNP rs ids as rows and samples as columns in this kind of format:

```
     dbSNP Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample
rs10000011     CC     CC     CC     CC     TC     TC
rs1000002      TC     TT     CC     TT     TT     TC
rs10000023     TG     TG     TT     TG     TG     TG
rs1000003      AA     AG     AG     AA     AA     AG
rs10000041     TT     TG     TT     TT     TG     GG
rs10000046     GG     GG     AG     GG     GG     GG
```

There are over a 1000 samples and 100s of 1000s of loci in this table, and I would like to do a massive Principal Component Analysis (with samples colored based on population).

In order to do that, I need to code my genotypes first. I was wondering, how would I do this (preferably in R/Python, as the file is too big for JMP Genomics)?

Also, I have some spots lacking data, which are indicated by `---` or `00`. I am going to standardize those to `NA` or `.` using a find and replace script, but how do I code it so R will still be able to run the PCA?

Comment: Most people here don't work with biology and don't know what genotype coding is. Can you briefly explain that and/or show your expected result?

Comment: If you provide sample code as to what you have tried I'm sure you'll get a lot more help. But this is either work or homework, given it's bioinformatics I wouldn't write the script for you, especially if this is going towards a paper, otherwise I'd have to be mentioned in the paper. If this is homework, then you should do research. I write my bioinfomatic scripts for a museum. If you're not that familiar with python, check out the book "bioinformatics programming using python" or the website Rosalind.info. Lastly look into scipy and biopython.

Comment: Have you tried `as.numeric`? You may have to adjust the numbers afterward to match your genotypes though.

Comment: Assuming each column has the same levels, then `as.numeric` mentioned above would work. However I worry more about the statistical properties of your methods; please see: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/can-principal-component-analysis-be-applied-to-datasets-containing-a-mix-of-cont

Comment: Again, I suggest that you add an expected result to your question. Making each nucleotides pair 0 or 2 is simple, but if there are other conditions then you either have to explain them or maybe try Biostars.

Comment: I vote to re-open as there is a valid straightforward answer provided by Nick K.

Answer (score 1):

While you could roll your own method to do this, I would suggest that for both the conversion and PCA that you use an established R package. One option would be `SNPRelate` which supports doing LD pruning and PCA ([tutorial](http://corearray.sourceforge.net/tutorials/SNPRelate/)). You'll need to convert your data into [plink](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink2) first. Plink can also recode your genotypes.

At bash command line for a table of genotypes as shown in the example:

```
<snpExample.txt head -n1 |cut -f2- | tr '\t' '\n' | perl -pe 's/(.*)/\1\t\1\t0\t0\t0\t0/' > snp.tfam
<snpExample.txt tail -n+2 | perl -pe's/\t([ACTG\-])([ACTG\-])/\t\1 \2/g;s/^([^ \t]+)/0\t\1\t0\t0/' > snp.tped
```

Now using plink (1.90):

```
plink --tfile snp --out snp --make-bed
```

recodes data as bed for import into SNPRelate in R using:

```
snpgdsBED2GDS(bed.fn, fam.fn, bim.fn, "test.gds")
```

Plink can also recode as numeric genotypes:

```
plink --tfile snp --out snp --recodeAD
```

Note that the matrix is the transpose of what you started with and there are heterozygote columns.